# SVG element background color

Tags: jquery, css, svg, background, path

I've got an `<svg>` element with a `<path>` which should draw a filled curve in the same grey color as my website's footer (See image).

*The issue is the light grey displayed in the background*, which should be white.

I've tried every CSS style I can think of with no joy.  Is this a browser issue?

I'm inserting the `<svg>` and `<path>` elements on a Squarespace 6 hosted template (non-developer mode) using jQuery.

EDIT: On a mac running 10.9.4, the grey is present in Firefox 31.0, **but not** in Chrome 37.0.2062.68 or Safari 7.0.5.  On iPhone and iPad running iOS 7.1.2 the grey **is present** in Safari for iOS, and Chrome 36.0.985.49.

EDIT #2: When I move the `<svg>` element to other locations on the page the background in question becomes white.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Zephyr

Note: The live site can be viewed at http://www.intuitivebythesea.com

---

[image: SVG Background Result]
<sub>(source: [squarespace.com](https://static.squarespace.com/static/53360641e4b0246ae8dfcf21/t/53e77f93e4b083c8a9bd0666/1407680403722/Screen%20Shot%202014-08-10%20at%209.08.09.png))</sub>

```
<footer id="footer">
    <svg id="curveUpColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="65">
        <path d="M0 100 C 20 0 50 0 100 100 Z"></path>
    </svg>
    <div class="footer-wrapper">...</div>
</footer>
```

Styles

```
/* Section Separator Styles */
    #curveUpColor path,
    #curveDownColor path {
        fill: #636363; 
        stroke: #636363;
    }
    #curveUpColor,
    #curveDownColor {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Comment: I can observe white color(chrome), what is your browser

Comment: @AshishBalchandani : I was just updating the question with that info!  On a mac running 10.0.4, the grey is present in Firefox 31.0, Safari for iOS, _**but not**_ in Chrome 37.0.2062.68 or Safari 7.0.5.

Comment: Weird.  It may be a painting bug in the browser.  I can't seem to make any path or shape truly white (#ffffff) in your example.

Comment: @Axel - ok, so I'm not missing something obvious then?

Comment: Not that I can see.  I would try taking the SVG element and placing it in a completely blank document and seeing if the same results occur.  That way you can eliminate any possibility of interfering code.

Comment: @Axel- I did as you suggested and the backgrounds are white.  There may be conflicting CSS, but I've changed every property in all the surrounding elements I can think of, without success.  Part of the issue is I'm not in total control of the CSS since it's a Squarespace template.

Comment: I also noticed that the `<svg>` displays correctly on all other pages on the site, except the main page - so the issue definitely lies there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  I found the issue - as was pointed out the issue was with a conflicting element on the main page - a template designed for parallax navigation.

The culprit was:

```
.content.has-main-image { 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 75px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

which created the "shadow" I was seeing.  Frustrating to say the least.

I can't say THANK YOU enough to @Axel for offering an alternative and elegant solution, and setting me on the path leading to this discovery.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same effect using pure CSS, if you're so inclined:

```
#footer:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #636363;
    border-radius: 100%;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -23px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 66;
}
```

then modify the CSS attributes for your `.back-to-top-link`

```
.collection-type-index .back-to-top-link {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -47px;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Results:

[image: CSS alt]

Comment: Wow.  I an so inclined - I much prefer to use only CSS for styling.  Let me try that out.

Comment: please see above for the solution to the original problem.  I much appreciate your time, and really like you're solution better, but will need to learn how to customize the example further - I've not used CSS to draw objects before.  My Client prefers the offset curve, vice the centered one.